# How can I add if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have use [elevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) jquery plugin. I want to disable elevateZoom in mobile(less than 600px width device).

So, How can I add(if condition) `zoomEnabled: false,` instead of `zoomEnabled: true,` in below jquery. when Open in mobile.

```
<script>
$("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({
    gallery:'gallery_01',
    zoomEnabled: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    galleryActiveClass: 'active'
</script>
```

Comment: Use [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: `zoomEnabled: isOnMobile`

Comment: @RahilWazir Can you please explain how to implement in our above script. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [.width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method in jquery to determine the width of the window and just change the object properties accordingly.

You can use it like this:

```
<script>
if ($( window ).width() < 600) {
  $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({
  gallery:'gallery_01',
  zoomEnabled: false,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  galleryActiveClass: 'active'
} else {
  $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({
    gallery:'gallery_01',
    zoomEnabled: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    galleryActiveClass: 'active'
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have try. but, I have not success. How can I add this in our above script. any idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A more readable approach (at least for me):

```
<script>
    $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({
        gallery:'gallery_01',
        zoomEnabled: ( $(window).width() >= 600 ),
        cursor: 'pointer',
        galleryActiveClass: 'active'
    });
</script>
```

but to be fair: read a javascript tutorial or 2 and you could've figured this out yourself.